# How to make a nonmagic user rise to power?

Tags: magic, fantasy-races, writing

I'd like to make a nonmagic user rise to power in my story dominated by magic users, but I can't think of a way that doesn't use magic in any way at all. I don't want the character to use any magical relic in his quest. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome Whiffler. Your question is story-based, unfortunately that is specifically one of our off-topic reasons. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways. enjoy the site. (If you can think of a way to [edit] your question to be on-topic, then by all means do so.)

Comment: How would an individual member of a discriminated-against minority rise to power?  History has examples.  Study them for ideas.

Comment: Too vague.   How powerful is magic?  What can it do?  Without this knowledge,  we can not tell even whether he should try something magic can not duplicate or a non-magical way to duplicate their work, and whether it would have to be better to impress them.

Comment: I partially agree with A Rogue Ant, in that it's written to be really focused on a character with all that implies. It might be wiser to ask about how people in general or a subset of people can face mages in your world. The reason for my vote to close is more simple : The use of magic (especially with the tag) needs to detail how such magic works. It's impossible to reasonably answer without it in this specific case.

Comment: I am the final close vote and I'd like to explain why. From the [help/on-topic] we read, "When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, **not to tell your story.**" Asking how a non-magic-using person can rise in power in a magic-using-dominated world is like asking how a woman can do so in a male-dominated world, or a homosexual in a heterosexual-dominated world. It has nothing to do with the rules of the world, but the plot and circumstances of your story - and we do not host questions about stories.

Comment: How does a non-programmer rise to power in a software development firm?  He has skills relevant to managing (or relevant to worming into positions of power).  In real life, the people in charge are not necessarily the most naturally powrful, but the most persuasive.

Answer (score 2):

Make them invent guns.

Wizards may be impressive and all, but guns can shoot wizards, and guns don't run out of bullets as fast as wizards run out of spells.

Comment: Answer only well asked questions

Answer (score 1):

**Democracy.**

The ability to rise to political power in a  democracy does not depend on any single easily-definable skill (except perhaps starting wealth and social position). The ability to rise to power depends on your ability to interact with other people.

You do not see world-class athletes or scientists or artists in many government positions. You do not even see many military, technology, or health specialists in elected positions of power. This is despite how the modern world is dominated by military, technology and health. Likewise in a world dominated by magic, being a powerful wizard will not help you get elected. Unless of course the position is Minister of the Arcane.

The good news is you can just base your character's political rise to power off an existing real person.

Comment: [Answer only well asked questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8484/80336) :p